# progressBarStyle not working on Android Studio

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a problem with Android Studio.

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/luisabsg/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/270e51d2bcfda0833b0b336f50197a8a/jetified-folioreader-0.5.4/res/layout/progress_dialog.xml","position":{"startLine":16}}],"original":"ERROR:/Users/luisabsg/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/270e51d2bcfda0833b0b336f50197a8a/jetified-folioreader-0.5.4/res/layout/progress_dialog.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyle not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/luisabsg/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/270e51d2bcfda0833b0b336f50197a8a/jetified-folioreader-0.5.4/res/layout/progress_dialog.xml:17: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyle not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyle not found.
```

You set the style of the progress bar to **`R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal`** . Finally

```
style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
```

**OR**

```
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

### FYI

> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/luisabsg/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/270e51d2bcfda0833b0b336f50197a8a/jetified-folioreader-0.5.4/res/layout/progress_dialog.xml:17

In your project app module
Goto :-  Your-Project-Location -> `/app/src/main/res/layout/` and create file `progress_dialog.xml`  and set below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_loading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/loading" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the problem is that when I change and then compile, it goes back to what it was before ... as if it didn’t save, even though i sync

Comment: @areatech How this possible. `Clean-Rebuilds-Restart`

Comment: https://youtu.be/qSgpi09MriU I made a short video demonstrating

Comment: @areatech This XML in your own xml or any libs xml?

Comment: I can't find this progress_dialog.xml file in my project, just in a folder on my computer

Comment: @areatech Yeah I assume that.

Comment: @areatech This XML is LOCKED. For test case change Textview property

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @areatech  For test case Under `ProgressBar` Change `TextView`'s textSize

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I have to change the                  
android: textSize = "18sp"
?

Comment: @areatech `I have to change the android: textSize = "18sp" ?` yes

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong styling attribute, you should use         `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"` in your progress style.

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"/>
```

Comment: I change it but every time I compile it, it goes back to android:progressBarStyle

Comment: Clean Project and Rebuild it.

Comment: Invalidate Caches and restart from File menu options

Comment: After changing your style from `style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyle"` to `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"`, did your error change or is it still the same?

Comment: it remains the same. I change and synchronize the project, it keeps changing. When I compile, it returns to what was written before. if you want, I can make my project available

Comment: Make it available.. it would be easier to help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rpNwfsEG88oDQwM8kA5dDw1XA3dvfL0J?usp=sharing

Comment: Allow access to drive link. You should share your code on github or any other version control management, it would be less hassle to download and running it.

Comment: I can't to share on github :( file is big

Comment: try https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rpNwfsEG88oDQwM8kA5dDw1XA3dvfL0J?usp=sharing